# Django views local variable 'varname' referenced before assignment and admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a simple view where I am capturing a post parameter and regex matching with an array. I use a local variable for that in the view.

When I open any model of myapp in the admin panel then it goes through checking all app files and gives me an error on using this local error as not referenced, which obviously gets value only when requests are made and regex is matched.

Why does it do that? Admin panel shouldn't complain about a local variable not referenced.  How to fix this?

Views

```
location = ['name1','name2','name3']

    @csrf_protect
    def locationnames(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            r = re.compile(request.POST['place'])
            found = list(filter(r.match, location))
        else:
            pass
        print (found)
        return JsonResponse(found, safe=False) #To Investigate for Security
```

Error on accessing any module on the app from the admin interface -

```
UnboundLocalError at /admin/myapp/names_location/
local variable 'found' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.0.0.99:8000/admin/myapp/names_location/
Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'found' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: /data/project/myapp/views.py in geonames, line 33
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['/data/project',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 29 Dec 2019 23:37:30 -0800
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. In case `if request.method == "POST":` evaluates `False` the variable `found` does not exist. Hence you get an error.

Comment: Correct. but didn't expect the admin panel to complain about that.

Comment: As far as I know, if you simply load up the admin site, there is not going to be a POST.

Answer (score 0):

only if conditions satisfied found variable can be assigned some values otherwise none so initialize the found variable globally

Comment: Correct. but didn't expect the admin panel to complain about that.